# React-Natice ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error

Tags: react-native, android-studio, installation

While installing react native, I am getting an error during host removal
the command i use

> npx react-native start

the error i got

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: got this error also when building a release apk

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is related to [Getting error 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719601/getting-error-digital-envelope-routines-reason-unsupported-code-err-oss)

Try setting below before running npx react-native start

export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Right, this will cause issues with release apk in iOS. I am wondering if adding the environment variable in the script in Bundle React Native code and images in the build phases might be ok for this. I can share how it goes. Once again seem its the node upgrade that might have triggered the issue. A nice read can be found below

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532