# How to set Storybook to run with different node version?

Tags: node.js, storybook

We had upgrade to node 17.4.0. After that Storybook started giving error on start:

`Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

From what I found it's because we use 17.x node. But unfortunately we can't downgrade, so I wanted to have two versions of node and be able to switch between them depending on what I do. I installed 16.x node: `nvm install v16.14.2` If I check currently used node version it will be 16.x, but when I run `npm run storybook` I see that it starts with version 17.x and fails. How can I setup my Storybook to be launching with version 16.x?

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json: change this line. and have a look on this as well (https://itsmycode.com/error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/)

Check this out
[Getting error 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719601/getting-error-digital-envelope-routines-reason-unsupported-code-err-oss)

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: it definitely should work can you show what error are you having in your terminal?

Comment: ` opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}`

Comment: I have edited the answer for you and have a look I have found one link maybe it could help. because in my it is working when I change to the "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when upgraded from node v16 to v18. Looks like Storybook uses Webpack 4 by default, so you have to add Webpack 5 and change the Storybook config to use that. This solved the issue for me.

See here:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19692#issuecomment-1297542268

Answer (score 0):

Add the snippet below to `.storybook/main.js` :

```js
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```