# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported (error Command failed with exit code 1.)

Tags: reactjs, node.js

yarn run v1.22.21
$ next build
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:

```
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
info  - Checking validity of types  

./components/BlogCard/index.tsx
24:25  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
24:25  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./components/CursorLover/index.tsx
77:9  Warning: React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'props.animationDuration' and 'props.animationFactor'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
115:26  Warning: The ref value 'attracterRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'attracterRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
117:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'onHover' and 'onLeave'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 
'attracterRef.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./components/InfiniteLoopingScrollView/index.tsx
34:8  Warning: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'backupHeight'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps  
37:5  Warning: React Hook useLayoutEffect contains a call to 'setHeight'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates. To fix 
this, pass [] as a second argument to the useLayoutEffect Hook.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:45539:9)
    at C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:29467:12
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:141008:10), <anonymous>:91:1)
-- inner error --
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:29141)
    at C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:31472
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Object.interpolateName (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:31381)
    at C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\copy-file-plugin.js:41:51
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:29141)
    at C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:31472
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Object.interpolateName (C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\loader-utils\index.js:1:31381)
    at C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\copy-file-plugin.js:41:51


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\lmfph\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-v2-main (1)>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

The yarn start is working with localhost:3000.

But whenever I start yarn build then, I am getting this error.

Comment: Older webpack uses hash(es) disabled in newer nodejs; update or use `--openssl-legacy-provider`. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719601/getting-error-digital-envelope-routines-reason-unsupported-code-err-oss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported