in shopware6.4 opensslErrorStack
In shopware6.4.20.0 I got this ERROR when I compile bin/build-storefront.sh:
`node:internal/crypto/hash:79
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen, algorithmId, getHashCache());
                  ^


Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:79:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at module.exports (/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:412:16)
    at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:444:10
    at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:320:13
    at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/`babel-loader/lib/index.js:55:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error',
    'error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported'
  ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}`

Node.js v20.16.0`


can someone help me please !
Thank you
should work bin/build-storefront.sh

shopware is using an apparently older version of webpack, which uses a hash algorithm (probably MD4) that is now obsolete and not supported by default in nodejs+OpenSSL after about 2021; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69692842 https://stackoverflow.com/q/69394632 https://stackoverflow.com/q/69665222 https://stackoverflow.com/q/69719601 . You need to either upgrade or configure webpack (if that works with shopware) or configure or (significantly) downgrade nodejs, and I can't comment on the shopware aspects; perhaps someone else will.
